# Using $(Configuration) macro in visual studio 2012 output path

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, macros

In Visual Studio 2012 I would like to direct output files according to the used configuration ether to ..\Debug\Output or to ..\Release\Output.

In Build section of the project properties I've specified

Output path: ..\$(Configuration)\Output for all configuration.

Expected result:

..\Debug\Output for Debug configuration
 ..\Release\Output for Release configuration

Instead:

..\$(Configuration)\Output

The macro $(Configuration) has been used verbally.

I also tried to use$(ConfigurationName) macro

Output path: ..\$(ConfigurationName)\Output

and got:

..\$(ConfigurationName)\Output

Are macros not supported for output path definition in Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: No, they are not supported for that setting.  Its kinda obvious.

Comment: I don't see why it's 'kinda obvious'?  The fact that it doesn't work in this instance may be down to some subtlety of syntax.